# Do certain packages in R counteract others

Tags: r

I am very new to R so bear with me. The data is not important in this occasion. The error and the code that makes it happen are below for context. I install and load the packages in the last section of code below. My question is if installing and then loading the packages listed below leads to this error. I have successfully executed this before with a shorter lineup of packages but have since lost that code and now hitting a wall with the rename error. Any thoughts on if this lineup counteracts each other?

```
 current %>%
 filter(AreaType=="State" & Ownership=="Private" & Industry=="10 Total, 
 all industries")->current
 last %>%
 filter(AreaType=="State" & Ownership=="Private" & Industry=="10 Total, 
 all industries")->last


 keepsc <- 
c("St","Year","JulyEmployment","AugustEmployment","SeptemberEmployment")
 current<- current[keepsc]

 keepsl <- 
 c("St","JulyEmployment","AugustEmployment","SeptemberEmployment")
 last<- last[keepsl]

 current<- rename(current,
```

---

```
 Error in rename(last, JulyEmployment17 = JulyEmployment, 
 AugustEmployment17 = AugustEmployment,  : 
 unused arguments (JulyEmployment17 = JulyEmployment, AugustEmployment17 
 = 
 AugustEmployment, SeptemberEmployment17 = SeptemberEmployment)


 #load packages
 x = c("tidyverse", "rgdal", "maptools", "mapproj", "rgeos", "plyr", 
 "RColorBrewer","scales", "viridis", "ggthemes", "tidyverse", "scales", 
 "cowplot","reshape","reshape2", "plotly")
 lapply(x, library, character.only = TRUE)
```

Comment: What is `rename` supposed to do and which package do you expect it to come from? You can do `package::rename(...)` where package is your expected package.

Comment: `rename` is a function in at least `dplyr` (loaded by `tidyverse`), `plyr` and `reshape`. You need to decide which you want to be using (probably `dplyr::rename` based on syntax)

Comment: Also you are loading `tidyverse` twice

Comment: When you loaded **plyr** after **dplyr** (in tidyverse) you probably got a fairly detailed warning about functions that were masked. When I do that, I get a very detailed warning message that specifically mentions the packages involved, the problem and the solution.

Comment: @joran, I will remove ggplot2, plyr, and the second iteration of tidyverse and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, packages have functions which have the same name. In order to avoid it you can use `packagename::function()`.

For example both `MASS` and `dplyr` have the same function called `select`.

```
### Example working 
df <- data.frame('may' = letters[1:4], 'be' = 1:4)
library(dplyr) 

df %>% select(may)

## Example not working 
detach('package:dplyr', unload = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)
df %>% select(may)
```